# Error Cannot call method "substring" of null in Script Values - PDI

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration, pdi

I'm using the PDI Spoon and wrote this script in Script Values to get values, check and transform:

```
var cte;
cte = gera_cte (CTRC.getString(), Numero_CTe.getString());
function gera_cte (arg1, arg2)
{
    if (arg2 == 0) {
        return arg1.substring(3,9); 
    }
    else 
    {
        return arg2.substring(4,10); 
    }    
}
```

But when the script read the last record, this happen:

```
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Erro inesperado
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleValueException: 
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 - Javascript error: 
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 - TypeError: Cannot call method "substring" of null (script#12)
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 - 
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.scriptvalues_mod.ScriptValuesMod.addValues(ScriptValuesMod.java:457)
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.scriptvalues_mod.ScriptValuesMod.processRow(ScriptValuesMod.java:692)
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60)
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2016/02/05 17:28:40 - Gera Num Cte.0 - Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "substring" of null (script#12)
```

How can I solve this issue, because is in the end of file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an extra line in your file, which makes it run with `null` values.

You should probably filter out the illegal rows before they reach your Java Script step, or check the input values in your function with something like:

```
function gera_cte (arg1, arg2)
{
    if (arg1 == null) {
        return arg1;
    }
    if (arg2 == 0) {
        return arg1.substring(3,9); 
    }
    else 
    {
        return arg2.substring(4,10); 
    }    
}
```

or setting `trans_Status = SKIP_TRANSFORMATION;` when the arguments are null.

Comment: Sure buddy, I have an extra line in the end and I didn't see, but your script solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing this script using the "Modified Javascript Value" step, you have this error because the javascript engine that PDI uses (Mozilla's Rhino engine) doesn't have a "substring" method. Try using "substr" instead:

```
// Perform the substring function
// 
// Usage:
// substr(var, from);
// substr(var, from, to);
//
// 2007-01-25
//
var str1= "Hello Pentaho!";
var str2= substr(str1, 6);
var str3= substr(str1, 6, 7);
Alert("Input : " + str1);
Alert("From position 6: " + str2);
Alert("From position 6 for 7 long : " + str3);
```